# Authorization Credentials Stripped — PHP, elastic beanstalk, oauth

Tags: php, angularjs, amazon-web-services, oauth

I'm noticing my Elastic Beanstalk-deployed Laravel 5.1 API and S3 Angular static app are stripping my Auth Credentials from my requests. My API is using https://github.com/lucadegasperi/oauth2-server-laravel for OAuth2.

I followed [this SO post on the issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22279301/authorization-credentials-stripped-django-elastic-beanstalk-oauth), but seems it's directly related to a **python** deployment.

My EB deployment is running:

> 64bit Amazon Linux 2015.09 v2.0.4 running PHP 5.6

When I check my localhost requests, I see the Access headers are present:

http://dde-api.localhost/1.0/me/1/dashboard

**Request**:

[image]

**Response**:

[image]

On Staging, they are stripped:

**Request**:

[image]

**Response**:

http://dde.staging.com.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com/html/pages/dashboard.html

[image]

Likewise, I've posted using `cURL` and `DHC` to my API to get a token as usual, then make an API request to `/dashboard`, which works locally, but throws error:

> { "error": "invalid_request", "error_description": "The request is
>   missing a required parameter, includes an invalid parameter value,
>   includes a parameter more than once, or is otherwise malformed. Check
>   the \"access token\" parameter." }

How can I solve this issue with PHP? Is `WSGIPassAuthorization` a Python thing?

Comment: I don't see an access token in either screenshot. Also you shared the responses not the requests.

Comment: @PeeHaa see above edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a bug in apache that strips the `Authorization` headers as it feels it isn't needed.

I solved it by modifying my Apache access rules file, `.htaccess`, (you can find this in your Laravel project), to check for this specific header, and make a copy of the header and pass it through:

```
# Handle Authorization Header
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
```