# AWS Elastic Load Balancer not Forwarding HTTP Headers to EC2 Instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, http-headers, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, elastic-load-balancer

I'm currently running a Python Flask Application on Amazon Elastic Beanstalk. When I test the application, it all works fine locally (I used Postman to send the GET & POST requests). However, on AWS, it doesn't work because the request that gets to my EC2 instances (behind the load balancer) does not include the **Authorization** header. It seems like the load balancer strips off the header. Is there something I'm doing wrong here?

Here's a comparison of what I get when I print out the header locally and on Elastic Beanstalk.

**Locally**

`[2017-07-04 13:18:14,650] [INFO] [common.decorators] Headers = Host: localhost:5000
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 151
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.110 Safari/537.36
Cache-Control: no-cache
Origin: chrome-extension://fhbjgbiflinjbdggehcddcbncdddomop
Content-Type: application/json
Authorization: Bearer ad9fd4d9-6ce6-497b-855a-dcebebdad65b
Postman-Token: xxxxx
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8`

**Elastic Beanstalk:**

`[2017-07-04 17:27:03,813] [DEBUG] [common.decorators] Headers = Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
Accept: */*
Host: dev.onetext.com
X-Forwarded-For: 66.30.13.108
Content-Type: application/json
Postman-Token: xxxxx
Connection: keep-alive
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch, br
X-Forwarded-Proto: https
Cache-Control: no-cache
X-Forwarded-Port: 443
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.110 Safari/537.36`

Comment: Refer https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=729128

Comment: See this question too: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22279301/authorization-credentials-stripped-django-elastic-beanstalk-oauth

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks to the comment added by @notionquest, I found the solution at https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=729128

I solved this by adding a new file under the .ebextensions folder with the following content:

`files:
  "/etc/httpd/conf.d/wsgihacks.conf":
    mode: "000644"
    owner: root
    group: root
    content: |
      WSGIPassAuthorization On`

Answer (score 4):

AWS do not accept unserscores **(_)** in headders, while we can use **(-)**, So Remove **underscores** from the header variables, example:- 
    header_var_val = "some value"
replace it with

```
headervarval = "some value"
```

It works for me