# not authorized to perform: rds:DescribeDBEngineVersions

Tags: apache, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, python-3.6

I implemented a `REST api` in `django` with `django-rest-framework`,on localhost working fine with successful results.

When pushing this up to an existing AWS elastic beanstalk instance, I received:

```
{
    "detail": "Authentication credentials were not provided."
}
```

For solution I followed this question : [Authorization Credentials Stripped](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22279301/authorization-credentials-stripped-django-elastic-beanstalk-oauth/34292480#34292480)

But when I push mycode on aws EB I am getting this error :

```
Pipeline failed with error "Service:AmazonRDS, is not authorized to perform: rds:DescribeDBEngineVersions"
```

I tried lots of solutions but every time I am getting this error.

Note: I am using python3.6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer of my problem.

I set the `RDS policy` and create new `custom_wsgi.config` file on `.ebextensions` directory and write command :

```
files:
  "/etc/httpd/conf.d/wsgihacks.conf":
    mode: "000644"
    owner: root
    group: root
    content: |
      WSGIPassAuthorization On
```